# Why can't I use hyperref and \C together?

Tags: macros, hyperref, math-operators

Today, I updated from TeXLive 2015 to TeXLive 2019 (about time, right?). However, I am having an issue that I haven't encountered before. I usually declare `\C` as a macro for the complex numbers. However, this collides with some implicit declaration of a command related to the `hyperref` package (which I also need).

I get the following error message:

`! LaTeX Error: Command \C unavailable in encoding TU.`

I checked the manual of the `hyperref` package, but they don't seem to define a command `\C`.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
$\C$
\end{document}
```

Note that this is unique to `\C`. The document compiles properly for `\R`.

Comment: `hyperref` preempts `\C`. Change the name.

Comment: Thanks. What does `\C` do in `hyperref`?

Comment: Please, avoid `minimal`. It is *not* for minimal examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use `article` the next time.

Comment: It is very annoying that hyperref defines a "\C" macro. I don't think final users are supposed to care more about name clash then package developers. I, myself, hate using \C for complexes. But coworkers do use it. I already evangelize too much to ask them to change their \C because hyperref sudently decide to pollute namespace. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `hyperref` needs to cover Unicode for producing bookmarks, it defines an own output encoding called `PU`.

In the file `puenc.def` we find

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\C}{PU}[1]{#1\83\017}% U+030F
```

so `\C` is used for the combining double grave accent.

You have two alternatives:

1. change the name of `\C` for the complex numbers to a different (perhaps better) name, such as `\sC` (set C) or what you like best;
2. undefine `\C`.

For the latter,

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\C\relax

\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

$\C$

\end{document}
```

Be careful with your bookmarks and be sure not to use that strange accent.

Comment: I normally just recommend using `\CC` kinda looks like the double nature of `\mathbb`

Answer (score 0):

I have perhaps hundred documents in which I use \C as a macro for \mathbf{C} and all of them are lost because of this collision. I wrote a python program for making substitutions of words in documents which I have run on all my *.tex documents to change \C for \CC (the double \ is necessary for python understand "\C"). Anyone interested can find substitui_palavra.py at http://www.calculo-numerico.sobralmatematica.org/programas/substitui_palavra.pyt  and change ".pyt" to ".py".